# how to add spark core and mllib and graphx dependency at the same time to spark project in scala IDE

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark-mllib

I have added spark-core and spark-graphx dependencies to my project like this

```
group Id: org.apache.spark
Artifact Id: spark-core_2.10
version: 1.6.1
```

and

```
group Id: org.apache.spark
Artifact Id: spark-graphx_2.10
version: 1.6.1
```

after entering these dependencies workspace will build correctly but when I want to add mllib library at first I dont know what version is consistent by spark core and graphx,I examined 1.3.0 and 1.1.0 exactly like two previous library, by following error in pom.xml

```
Failure to transfer org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10:jar:2.0.0-M8 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10:jar:2.0.0-M8 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10:jar:2.0.0-M8 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10:jar:2.0.0-M8 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.run(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

also I fixed scala libraries to 2.10 version.
how can I add these dependencies in my project?
(I could add all of them in windows but now I am working in Linux Os)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Internet connection was slow and Scala IDE couldn't access to dependencies.
I have added all dependencies under 1.6.1 version. these are running well now.